# Defining the precision/size of a double or float at runtime

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-manipulation, precision

I'm creating a C++ digital signal application, which requires the precision, or size, of the operands to be set at runtime.

I'm aware that typically, `double` and `float` types are guaranteed a minimum length by IEEE 754 standard, however as with `int` types, these are only minimum lengths.

What options are available to define floating point types of customisable length, to be defined at runtime? Ideally, an existing library or type, however my other crude idea would be to use a bit-mask to remove the last *n*-bits of a number after each operation.

Comment: I suspect that you've misunderstood something. There's no general way to  set the size of floating-point operands at runtime. Masking extra bits, as you've suggested will make things horribly slow, which is anathema in digital signal processing.

Comment: Use `int` with numerator and denumerator ?

Comment: IEEE 754 defines several *exact* sizes. You are looking for an external library, which is off-topic.

Comment: @EJP I'm looking for any effective way to meet my requirement which could be standard library or a method discussed below

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using [union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)?

```
union S
{
    std::int32_t n;     // occupies 4 bytes
    std::uint16_t s[2]; // occupies 4 bytes
    std::uint8_t c;     // occupies 1 byte
};
```

Since there is people who can't go to the WebPage cited, try the example of:

```
   Union S
{
    Double H;
    float L;
};
```

You will be using the same space, but assigning the corresponding value to the variable needed.

Answer (score 0):

did you consider "bit fields"? it works for integral types though.
or may be, you can make thing a bit custom tailored, by storing the decimal type in one part and integral part in two different variables in the struct and set their bit fields. Something like...

```
struct Number{
int integral:4;
int decimal:6;
};
```